# Get compilate date

Tags: linux, command-line, c++

I am trying to extract the compilation date from a linux command (or cpp would be fine too). I am using:

```
stat -c %z ./myProgram.bin
```

However, if I copy `myProgram.bin` to an another place via ssh for example, the stat command is basically giving me the date of the copy.

How can I get the real compilation date?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Thomas Dickey's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/284151/86440) addresses the issue in general, for any (ELF) binary. Given the way your question's phrased, you might find the [`__DATE__` and `__TIME__` predefined macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html) useful; they allow the compilation date and time to be referred to within a program (so a program knows its own compilation date and time).

Here's a quick example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("This program was compiled on %s at %s.\n", __DATE__, __TIME__);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! It is exactly what I was looking for! I was using fp = popen(command, "r") to use the linux stat command inside my cpp progam. Thanks a lot

Comment: Ok! I removed it and I put it directly on stackoverflow. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy preserving the modification time, e.g.,

```
cp --preserve=timestamps source destination
```

or (more generally: *mode*, *ownership* and *timestamps*)

```
cp -p source destination
```

although in some cases, preserving *ownership* is not wanted.

Similarly, you can copy to remote systems using scp's `-p` option:

```
scp -p source remote:destination
```

but `scp` does not have separate options for the mode, etc.  Since it runs with the given *remote* permissions, it does not have a feature for setting remote ownership at the same time.  Because of these limitations, you might want to use `tar` to make an archive which you extract on the remote system, preserving as much information as possible.

The ELF format used for binary files does not include a date, so the file's modification timestamp is all that you can preserve.

Further reading:

- [elf - format of Executable and Linking Format (ELF) files](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html)
- [cp - copy files and directories](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html)
- [scp — secure copy (remote file copy program)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scp.1.html)

Comment: `cp` isn't quite as useful when copying files "via ssh", but `scp` knows about `-p` too.

Answer (score 0):

`stat -c %z` displays last creation/updating time of file and it's not changeable or preservable. Hence if you copy the file to other place, it will always get new now creation time. What are you looking for is `stat -c %y`, to display last modification time, which is usually preserved by most tools dealing with files and directories.